# Minimum order for free shipping in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento version 1.8.1.0 and I need to place a minimum amount and when I checked in system --> configuration --> Free shipping. I could not find the field Minimum Order Amount. My table looks like this.

[image: admin]

Can any one tell me that o will I set minimum purchase amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with current configuration scope as **website or default**.

[image: Configuration scop]

Comment: but i have multi store and i need to update it in only one store. will it make any changes to the other store?

Comment: @hakkim set current configuration scope as website. It will only apply to selected store only

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did as you said. But still minimum mount does not appear while i check out. showing "Free Shipping on Order Over Rs0.00".

Comment: @hakkim How it will show minimum amount for free shipping? You have asked for free shipping and again in the comments you are mentioning as "minimum amount does not appear while I checkout". with out mentioning the minimum order amount, how magento knows your minimum amount???? First ask your question correctly. Then you will get correct answer.

Comment: @Pavan Kumar :D That's what was my question. How will I let magento know my minimum amount for free shipping.

Comment: @hakkim you can give minimum order amount in "Minimum Order Amount" field

Answer (score 1):

Hakkim
According to you picture,your `Current Configuration Scop  is  a store_view,Magento are showing minimum order amount` when you have Selecting  `Current Configuration Scope:` as  Website or Default Config.